# Is it ok to comment out joint state publisher node from turtlebot package?

Tags: ros, joint, turtlebot, state, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i comment it out i am getting an error showing there is no transformation between basefoot print and the left and right wheels.
How to remove this error? Will the error go if i give some joint velocities for the turtle bot wheels?

My problem is this..I need to connect a turtlebot arm to the turtlebot . So i called the xacro file of the turtlebot arm from the turtlebot_library.urdf.xacro. So when i launch the turtlebot in rviz the turtlebot with arm comes with the joint_state_publisher python tab where i can control the the joint states of the arm joints and the bot wheels.

But when i run the arm controller the arm is vibrating back and forth between the position given by the joint_state_publisher and the arm controller. So i searched how to stop this..then i found in a website to comment out joint_state_publisher if arm controler is used.But when i comment out it, a error is showing in turtlebot tires (when launched in rviz) saying there is no transformation between left and right wheells with base_foot print.... (but the vibration of the arm stops and the controller works fine)

So is there any way to stop publishing the joint states of the arm instead of commenting out the joint_state_publisher of turtlebot or will the error will be resolved if i send some position messages to the turtlebot wheels?

Please help...thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221894/is-it-ok-to-comment-out-joint-state-publisher-node-from-turtlebot-package?/) by [npa](https://answers.ros.org/users/24133/npa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-12-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) on 2015-12-02**:
where do you see the error? In RViz or somewhere else? Can you copy the full text and path of the file you have modified?

**Comment by [npa](https://answers.ros.org/users/24133/npa/) on 2015-12-06**:
in rviz.... i just commented out joint_state_publisher node in rviz launch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not recommended to comment it out.

It's ok to comment it out if you don't want transforms in your system. As you've observed without it publishing the joint states, robot_state_publisher cannot publish the transforms for the different links.

So if you publish the wheel states then you will be replicating the joint_state_publisher.

Why do you want to comment ou tthe joint state publisher?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0